# $resource HTTP status AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I am trying to really wrap my mind on how to use $resource to get the HTTP status code that was passed back I have this factory I have setup with one way I have tried to implement getting the HTTP header with no success.

**app.js**

```
.factory("Resource", function ($resource, baseUrl) {
            return $resource(baseUrl + "rest/sessionId",
                {},
                {getSessionId: {method: "GET"}},
                get:
            {
                method: 'GET'
                interceptor: {
                    response: function (response) {
                        var result = response.resource;
                        result.$status = response.status;
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            );
        })
```

Comment: do you need the header or the status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Angularjs, I suggest you to use the $http Service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  header:{"content-type":"text"},
  url: '/baseUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

          console.log(response.status)

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Otherwise you need to use an interceptor, but to my point of view is currently and overkill:

```
.factory("Resource", function ($resource, baseUrl) {
    var resource = $resource(url, {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
            interceptor: {
                response: function(response) {      
                    var result = response.resource;        
                    result.$status = response.status;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }                            
    });

return resource;
});
```

you can return it from the factory.

Comment: unfortunately it is already setup wit all of my factories to use $resource.... however the interceptor is not a bad idea. How would you apply it to my code.

Comment: can i just add the interceptor to the factory? I really dont know how to apply to my situation.